# Why does this alert 5?

Tags: javascript

Curious bit of code here...

```
var x = 5;

function fn() {
    x = 10;
    return;
    function x() {}
}
fn();
alert(x);
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7tRR/)

Is `function x() {}` called at all after `return` ?
Why not alert 10?

Comment: Bizarre... If you comment out the `function x()...` line, it alerts `10`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`function x() {}` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) to the start of `fn`'s scope, and this effectively makes `x` a local variable before `x = 10;` is evaluated.

<s>The function is *not* set to `10`.</s>

**Update:** The sentence above is wrong. `x` is actually set to `10`. `var` is not used to declare it, but even if it was, the last sentence in the quote below only refers to the *declaration* part of the name `x`, not its *assignment* to `10`.

From MDN (emphasis mine):

> **function**
>
> Three forms with different scope behavior:
>
> - **declared**:
>     as a statement at the parent function top-level
>
>   - behaves like a var binding that gets initialized to that function
>   - initialization "hoists" to the very top of the parent function, **above vars**
>
> **var**
>
> - function-scoped
> - hoist to the top of its function
> - **redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are no-ops**

Comment: Do you mean "precede" instead of "supersede"? The `x = 10` is still evaluated and the function overwritten by `10`.

Comment: @user, whoops, you're absolutely right, I took into account a `var`  keyword that was not there. Thanks for the heads-up, I'll fix this right away.

Answer (score 3):

function x float to the top, so you assigning the function to 10

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring function x within fn; therefore, you are using the locally scoped version of x. It doesn't matter at what point the function x is declared. What you are actually doing when you set x to 10 is you are setting the function of x to 10.

Answer (score 2):

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/jmVNX/) also alerts 5:

```
var x = 5;

function fn() {
    x = 10;
    return;
    var x;
}
fn();
alert(x);​
```

The important point is that you are declaring a **local variable** `x`. Declaring a variable *after* the return statement also doesn't matter - it is still a local variable.

Remove the declaration and you get 10 instead because the `x` is no longer a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the way variable hoisting works in JavaScript. Variable declarations are hoisted but not their assignemnts. Function declarations are also hoisted together with the function body (although function expressions are not).

So your code is effectively doing this:

```
 var x = 5;

 function fn() {
     var x;
     x = function () {}
     x = 10;
     return;
 }
 fn();
 alert(x);
```

The `x` within the function is hence declared with only local scope and does not affect the `x` decalred in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `fn` is an object, and `x` is a property of that object.  Local-scope always takes precisence over globals.

Comment: This is totally wrong. The `x` is not a property of the function object.

Comment: In JavaScript there's a clear distinction between variables and properties. The `x` defined by the function declaration creates a variable that has no direct relationship with the `fn` object. A variable scope is created by invoking the function object, but the variables never become properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

X in fn() is a function 
but x in the global scope is a var

remove the  function x() {} part and x will be alerted 10